# is there any way to customize the buttons generated by activeadmin formbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs "Mission" do
      f.input :level
      f.input :points
      f.input :title
      f.input :description
    end

    f.has_many :requirements do |r|
      r.input :kind, as: :select, collection: %w(text video image)
      r.input :count
      r.input :description, as: :text
    end

    f.actions
  end
```

This is actually generating an "Add New Requirement" button at the bottom of the form. Now i would like to customize that button like want add custom id or want to change the name , how can i do that

Answer (score 1):

ActiveAdmin's form uses Formtasic under the hood, and the actions supports [passing a block](https://github.com/formtastic/formtastic/blob/master/lib/formtastic/helpers/actions_helper.rb#L58) where you can render pretty much what you'd like. For example:

```
<%= f.actions do %>
  <%= f.action :submit, label: 'My text', id: 'some-id' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: i think this will add new button bt i want to get control over existing button "Add New Requirement"

Comment: @Abubakkarsiddique You can't get a handle on the existing button but you can override it as I show you in my answer. I suggest reading the documentation I linked to.